# Marking a one-to-many relationship as not updatable or insertable in hyperjaxb3

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have this XSD definition that I use to generate JPA objects via Hyperjaxb3. Basically, what I need is that the generated class will give me access to the column and not to the entity. I want to be able to modify the **CASE_ID** field directly and not through the entity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.sample.code/types"
    targetNamespace="http://www.sample.code/types"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:complexType name="CaseType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Entity 1
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="priority" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element name="elements" type="ws:ElementType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Case" type="ws:CaseType" />

    <xsd:complexType name="ElementType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Entity 2
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
            <xsd:element name="creation_date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="element_type" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="case" type="ws:CaseType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Element" type="ws:ElementType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

This is part of the configuration file **binding.xjb**

```
    <bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='CaseType']">
        <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='id']">
            <hj:id>
                <orm:generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
            </hj:id>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='elements']">
            <hj:one-to-many>
                <orm:join-column name="CASE_ID"/>
            </hj:one-to-many>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='ElementType']">
        <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='case']">
            <hj:many-to-one>
                <orm:join-column name="CASE_ID"/>
            </hj:many-to-one>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='id']">
            <hj:id>
                <orm:generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
            </hj:id>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
```

This works perfectly. Howhever, this generates a field like this.

```
/**
 * Obtient la valeur de la propriété case.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link CaseType }
 *     
 */
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = CaseType.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID")
public CaseType getCase() {
    return _case;
}

/**
 * Définit la valeur de la propriété case.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link CaseType }
 *     
 */
public void setCase(CaseType value) {
    this._case = value;
}
```

What I need is a way to modify the hyperjaxb configuration to be able to generate something like this:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = CriminalCaseType.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public CriminalCaseType getCase() {
    return _case;
}

.
.
.


@Basic
@Column(name = "CASE_ID")
public BigInteger getCaseId() {
    return _caseId;
}

public BigInteger setCaseId(BigInteger value) {
    this._caseId = value;
}
```

Being this **@JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)** the part I can't figure out how to configure in my **binding.xjb** file so I can define my complex type like this

```
    <xsd:complexType name="ElementType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Entity 2
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
            <xsd:element name="case_id" type="xsd:integer" />
            <xsd:element name="creation_date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="element_type" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="case" type="ws:CaseType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Element" type="ws:ElementType" />
```

Comment: That's it. How can I mark this comment as a solution? I don't think I can, can I? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
<orm:join-column name="CASE_ID" updatable="false" insertable="false"/>
```

See [this schema](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/persistence/src/main/resources/persistence/orm/orm_1_0.xsd#L1034-L1035), it documents the customizations schema for HJ3.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Hyperjaxb3](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3).